# Publishing Silverlight application that uses WCF to connect to database

Tags: c#, silverlight, fiddler

I have a silverlight application that works perfectly on my local machine but, when i try to run it from a web server it does not work.

I've been researching a lot and i ended up installing the fiddler web debugger tool which gave me a little better idea of why my application was failing. I think the way i'm connecting to the database is whats causing my issue. This is what i'm using:

```
string myConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=Database;server=Server;Connection Timeout = 600";
```

After a little bit of research i learned that `Integrated Security = SSPI` means that the current machines credentials will be used to connect to the database which is why the program works on my computer and not the webserver.

I don't know if i'm thinking about this correctly, but i'm pretty sure this is my problem. The error that Fidder reports is: `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN'`.

I also read that I should specify userId and password in the connection string, but i don't know what values to use for these fields (when i connect to sql server 2008 i use Windows Authentication option and i only supply a user name.)

I can post any code that may help to clarify my situation.

Edit: if it helps at all, i am able to visit DatabaseService.svc in the browser without any errors.

What do i have to do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you change the identity of the AppPool under which the service is running to the one you use to connect to database ?

Comment: Are your 'database=Database' and 'server=Server' entries accurate?

Comment: @prthrokz I changed the identity to NetworkService, but it still did not work.

Comment: @Brian, yes the database and server entries are accurate, i just replaced them with 'Database' and 'Server' in this question. I am able to run my application perfectly locally.

Comment: @rage I think you should change it to your Windows Account as you mentioned on the local box you connected using Windows Authentication

Comment: @prthrokz I tried this and ran it locally first to see if it would work, and i get an error saying that Login failed for my specified user name.

Comment: Weird as you said you connect to local instance with Windows Authentication. I can only think of now creating a new user at the server and enabling SQL server authentication for the user and then supplying username and password in conn string

Comment: does it matter that i have never had to use a password to connect to the local instance?